# Can I restore disk after ntfsclone

Tags: data-recovery

So I stupidly got the order of arguments the wrong way in my ntfsclone command and ended up writing a blank disk to the disk I primarily use for important data (documents, personal pictures, etc).

There was nothing on the source disk so it wouldn't have written much.
I'm *hoping* that there might be a way to recover my data?

I used

```
sudo ntfsclone --overwrite /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdd1
```

Comment: Does `photorec` still find something?

Comment: It seems to be finding some files. So far none of them have the correct file names and it's dumping them all into the one directory but it's a great start!

Comment: @frostschutz After a few days I've managed to recover files to an external drive just to be safe. Now I'm trying to see if I can restore the earlier partition using TestDisk. The thing is, I have no idea how to tell if it's found my previous partition or the new partition after the ntfsclone debacle. Any ideas?